# how to get transaction status?

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, transaction, signature, explorers

I didn't find the answer in old posts. so I decided to ask again.

So. how to get transaction status. having her signature?

I tried this. but I always got null or error

```
  // not working
  const checkStatusBuying = await connection.getSignatureStatuses([successSign], {
    searchTransactionHistory: true
  })

  // deprecated, not working
  const checkStatusBuying = await connection.getConfirmedTransaction(successSign)
```

```
TransactionExpiredTimeoutError: Transaction was not confirmed in 30.00 seconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can for example do this:

```
const txSig = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
      provider.connection,
      transaction,
      [wallet.payer, mint]
      , { skipPreflight: true, commitment: "processed"}
    );

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  const res = await connection.getSignatureStatuses([txSig]);
  console.log(res);
}
```

This will print you the confirmation status every second.

Looking like this:

```
{
  context: { apiVersion: '1.17.17', slot: 23 },
  value: [
    {
      confirmationStatus: 'confirmed',
      confirmations: 21,
      err: null,
      slot: 2,
      status: [Object]
    }
  ]
}
```

Usually confirmed it the perfect confirmation status. It means that 66% of stake voted for the transactions. There has never been a confirmed transaction that did not finalize.

So usually this is all you need:

```
const txSig = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
      provider.connection,
      transaction,
      [wallet.payer, mint]
      , { skipPreflight: true, commitment: "confirmed"}
    );
```

Comment: const res = await connection.getSignatureStatuses([sign])
always returns null.  {
  context: { apiVersion: '1.17.20', slot: 248453968 },
  value: [ null ]
}

Comment: You may need to wait a bit until it was processed.